# How to save one parent entity and multiple child entities in single transaction using spring/hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a project where i have a parent entity and multiple child entities
e.g: `

> Parent Entity -> Employee, and Child Entities -> EmployeeAddress,
>   EmployeeContact etc.

My question is what is the industry standard to save relation like this in single save method. Because i want `employee-id` to be present in all child entities.
Does hibernate provide any solution for these scenarios, or do we have to manually set foreign keys after parent entity is created and then save the child entities.

Thank you.

Comment: If your relations are bidirectionals, set synchronize both sides of the relation and save the owning side (your `Employee` ?). You must have the `cascade` option set to cascade the parent`s persist operation.

Comment: Can you give an example, so that it will be more clear.

Comment: [This post](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/) may help you.

Comment: Not just hibernate. All JPA providers allow parent child relationships via *toOne and *ToMany relationships. You can just search web for everything. Please use this forum when you have code issues with example code that you have issue with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hibernate` has `OneToMany` annotation for saving and selecting of parent class. Let's create relations like following:

```
@Entity
public class Employee{

  @Id
  private int id;

  private String fullName;

  private double salary;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
  private List<Contact> contacts;
}

@Entity
public class Contact{

   @Id
   private int id;

   private String phoneNumber;

   private String address;

}
```

Save method:

```
public void save(){
  Employee employee = new Employee();
  employee.setFullName("John Smith");
  employee.setSalaru(5000);

  Contact contact1 = new Contact("+19874561232","Wall Street 10"); 
  Contact contact2 = new Contact("+11234561232","Green Street 10");
  List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList();
  contacts.add(contact1);
  contacts.add(contact2);
  employee.setContacts(contacts);

  session.save(employee);
}
```

[You can learn more about OneToMany.](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/)